# How do I do operations with numeric strings inside an array (in powershell)?

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

So lets say my variable `$a` is an array containing "1" and "2" as string.

> $a = "1", "2"

Now I want to use `foreach` through a pipeline to subtract 1 from each value, so I'd do something like

> $a | foreach{$_ = [int]$_ - 1}

but this seems do nothing, yet produces no error. So `$a` still contains "1" and "2". I struggle to understand where I went wrong... It's possible if i don't have an array, so this works:

> $b = "3"; $b - 2

And it will return 1. So I also tried without "[int]" but it still fails, so I'm guessing it either has to do with the pipeline or my `foreach` but I wouldn't know why it does that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `foreach` isn't mutating the items in your original array like you think it is - you're assigning the calculated value to the context variable `$_`, not updating the array index.

You can either create a new array with the calculated values as follows:

```bsh
$a = $a | foreach { [int]$_ - 1 }
```

or mutate the items in the original array in-place:

```bsh
for( $i = 0; $i -lt $a.Length; $i++ )
{
    $a[$i] = [int]$a[$i] - 1
}
```

Note that your second example doesn't quite do what you think either:

```bsh
PS> $b = "3"; $b - 2
1
PS> $b
3
```

The `$b - 2` part is an *expression* which is evaluated and echoed out to console - it doesn't change the value of `$b` because you haven't assigned the result of the expression back to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the instance variable to the last line of your loop like so:

```
$a = $a | foreach{$_ = [int]$_ - 1; $_}
```

Comment: I suggest  `$a = $a | foreach{ [int]$_ - 1 }`, which is not only more more concise and efficient, it also avoids assigning to an _automatic variable_ (`$_`), which should generally be avoided.